# Latin Hypercube Sampling from a Normal Distribution (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, sampling, normal-distribution

I want to use the Latin Hypercube sampling method to select points uniformly from a Normal Distribution. If I have the line below which gives me a Normally Distributed set of data, how would I then go about applying the Latin Hypercube method to it?

```
d = 3*t +0.00167*randn(1000,1);
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work. Some code that demonstrates your problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for lhsnorm function

you can read about it here [lhsnorm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lhsnorm.html)